# find string within list of strings

Tags: kotlin

```
validValueType.ValueTypeGroup

["\"is_enabled\": false", "\"value\":\"OUT\""]
    
failedRecord.record
{"email":"test@gmail.com","source":"web","value":"OUT","reate_date":"2022-09-29T03:42:09.976-05:00","is_undeliverable":false}
    
        fun publishAlert(failedRecord: Record<String>) {
            if (validValueType.ValueTypeGroup.contains(failedRecord.record)) {
             // do stuff
    
            } else {
                // no match do other stuff
            }
        }
```

In the list above there are two strings I want to check for when this function receives a record.

The failedRecord.record string does contain what I want "value":"OUT" and it's also within the list above. So why is contains not working here? it keeps bouncing out to the else statement.

Comment: What is the datatype of `validValueType.ValueTypeGroup` and `failedRecord.record`?

Generally for Maps, programming languages have containsKey() or similar method

Comment: @kartoos validValueType.ValueTypeGroup is a list<string> 
and failedRecord.record is a String

Comment: It does not seem like `failedRecord.record` is string as per your post, it looks like a map. What is the value of `failedRecord.record` then? Is it "value" or "OUT" or anything else?

Comment: "\"is_enabled\": false"
      "\"value\":\"OUT\""
this is how they look there is no value it's a string @kartoos

Comment: Try this `println(failedRecord.record::class.qualifiedName)` to check the type

Comment: it returned kotlin.String @kartoos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `any()` in the list and pass a predicate: 
`{x -> searchString.contains(x)}`

The searchString.contains() will search `x` as a substring inside `searchString` for each x representing the elements in the list

```kotlin
var list = listOf("\"is_enabled\": false", "\"value\":\"OUT\"")
println(list)
println(list::class.qualifiedName)
println() // empty newline
    
var searchString = "{\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\",\"source\":\"web\",\"value\":\"OUT\",\"create_date\":\"2022-09-29T03:42:09.976-05:00\",\"is_undeliverable\":false}";
println(searchString)
println(searchString::class.qualifiedName)
println() // empty newline
    
println(list.any{x -> searchString.contains(x)});
```

Output

```bash
["is_enabled": false, "value":"OUT"]
java.util.Arrays.ArrayList

{"email":"test@gmail.com","source":"web","value":"OUT","create_date":"2022-09-29T03:42:09.976-05:00","is_undeliverable":false}
kotlin.String

true
```

Comment: the string i'm searching through is {"email":"test@gmail.com","source":"web","value":"OUT","create_date":"2022-09-29T03:42:09.976-05:00","is_undeliverable":false}



and i want to see if it contains any value within the list = listOf("\"is_enabled\": false", "\"value\":\"OUT\"")

Comment: @AnthonyEdwardsStan I have updated the answer accordingly, see if it helps

Comment: `{ x -> searchString.contains(x) }` could be `{ x -> x in searchString }`, or simply `{ it in searchString }`.